# Why can a parent send data only once in a bidirectional channel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

The child process can send as much data as it wants, but the parent process can send it once, then the program stops and waits for something (i don't know what). The channel is open, i can't understand why it happen...
I have already looked at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.connection), but there is no example in bidirectional channel, only unidirectional channel.

**Code:**

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe, current_process
from multiprocessing.connection import wait

def foo(w, i):
    print("w -> 1234")
    w.send("1234")

    readers = []

    readers.append(w)

    while readers:
        for r in wait(readers):
            try:
                msg = r.recv()
            except EOFError:
                print("w: error")
                readers.remove(r)
            else:

                if(msg == "1234"):
                    w.send("4321")
                    print("1234 -> w -> 4321")

                if(msg == "4321"):
                    print("4321 -> w")
                    print("w: close")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    readers = []
    r, w = Pipe(duplex=True)
    readers.append(r)
    p = Process(target=foo, args=(w, 1))
    p.start()
    w.close()

    while readers:
        for r in wait(readers):
            try:
                msg = r.recv()
                if(msg == "1234"):
                    r.send("1234")
                    print("1234 -> r -> 1234")

                if(msg == "4321"):
                    r.send("r: 4321")
                    print("4321 -> r -> 4321")

            except EOFError:
                print("r: error")
                readers.remove(r)
```

**Current output:**

```
w -> 1234
1234 -> r -> 1234
1234 -> w -> 4321
4321 -> r -> 4321
```

Expected output:

```
w -> 1234
1234 -> r -> 1234
1234 -> w -> 4321
4321 -> r -> 4321
4321 -> w
w: close
```

Comment: What is the second argument of `foo` (`i`) intended to be used for? It seems to be unused.

Comment: @alani, you're right, it's really not used anywhere, but without it the code doesn't run

Comment: Well it seems in the end that the problem is simply that you are sending `"r: 4321"` when it is expecting simply `"4321"`, and removing the `r: ` seems to fix it.

Comment: ".. .without it the code doesn't run." Did you say `p = Process(target=foo, args=(w))` or `p = Process(target=foo, args=(w,))` (with a comma after the `w`)?

Comment: +1 to @Booboo, it is perfectly possible to use a 1-element tuple here if you get the syntax correct. Separately from that, your variable names `r` and `w` for the two ends of the pipe are unhelpful given that it is bidirectional - the docs suggest `parent_conn` and `child_conn`.

Comment: But given the nature of what I believe to be the actual fix (need to use `"4321"` in place of `"r: 4321"`), I am voting to close as "caused by a typo".

Comment: @alani, the names of variables should't affect the operation of the program, or I did't understand something with bidirectional tunnels?) Can you tell more about it?

Comment: @alani, your suggestion solved my problem, thank you